# How can I increase the width of a tabularray table?

Tags: tables, floats, tabularray

I am having trouble increasing the width of a `tblr` environment:

```tex
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        % Doesn't do anything.
        width      = 5in,
        hlines,
        vlines,
        cell{1}{1} = {r=1,c=3}{halign=c},
        cell{2}{1} = {r=1,c=3}{halign=c},
        cell{3}{1} = {r=1,c=2}{halign=c},
        cell{3}{3} = {r=3,c=1}{halign=c},
        cell{4}{1} = {r=1,c=2}{halign=c},
        cell{5}{1} = {r=1,c=2}{halign=c},
        cell{6}{1} = {r=1,c=3}{halign=c}
    }
        \texttt{<header>}  & & \\
        \texttt{<nav>}     & & \\
        \texttt{<section>} & & \Mono{<aside>} \\
        \texttt{<article>} & & \\
        \texttt{<article>} & & \\
        \texttt{<footer>}  & & \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{HTML Semantics Example}
    \label{fig:html_semantics_example}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I expected the `<section>` and `<article>` columns to have twice the width of the `<aside>` column, but they do not. I thought this could be fixed by increasing the width of the whole table.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify the total width, you need to choose some columns which can expand, e.g. `X`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={X[halign=c,2]X[halign=c]},
        width      = 4in,
        hlines,
        vlines,
        cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{},
        cell{2}{1} = {c=2}{},
        cell{Z}{1} = {c=2}{},        
        cell{3}{2} = {r=3}{},
    }
        \texttt{<header>}   & \\
        \texttt{<nav>}      & \\
        \texttt{<section>}  & \texttt{<aside>} \\
        \texttt{<article>}  & \\
        \texttt{<article>}  & \\
        \texttt{<footer>}   & \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{HTML Semantics Example}
    \label{fig:html_semantics_example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]